# Multiple frames in Tkinter while using Python

Tags: python, user-interface, terminal, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I have been trying to get a simple GUI working which accepts a string using an entry form, included in the Tkinter module, and, depending on which container it is in, either runs "killall + string" or "open + string" through terminal. Below is my code that I am using.  The problem is in line 8 and the comments above explain in more detail what is wrong.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()
def buttonPressed():
    # this is the problem in the program.
    # it keeps returning [''] in the print statement and doesn't quit
    # any applications
    listOfApps = form1.form.get().split(',')
    # the print is just so i can see the output
    print(listOfApps)
    # goes through each item in list and kills them(yes i know there are much easier
    # ways to do this, i'm just trying to learn a bit about GUI and the os module
    for i in listOfApps:
        try:
            os.system("killall " + i)
        except:
            pass
def buttonPressed2():
    filesToOpen = form2.form.get().split(', ')
    for i in filesToOpen:
        try:
            os.system("open " + i)
        except:
            pass
class form_and_submit:
    def _init_(self):
        pass
    #creates an instance of a form with seperate variables for button text, buton command, and color of the frame
    def create_container(self, buttonText, buttonCommand, color):
        #Creating all widgets/containers
        self.container = Frame(root)
        self.form = Entry(self.container)
        self.button = Button(self.container)
        #defining variables for all widgets/containers
        root['background'] = color
        self.container['background'] = color
        self.button['text'] = buttonText
        self.button['command'] = buttonCommand
        self.form['background'] = color
        self.form['border'] = '5'
        self.form['highlightthickness'] = '0'
        #Packing all widgets/containers
        self.container.pack()
        self.form.pack()
        self.button.pack()
#creating forms and putting them in root with desire attributes
form1 = form_and_submit
form2 = form_and_submit
form1.create_container(form1, 'kill matching processes', buttonPressed, 'red')
form2.create_container(form2, 'Open desired files', buttonPressed2, 'blue')
#starts up window
root.mainloop()
```

I believe the problem here is within the multiple frames because it worked fine before with just form1 as an instance of class form_and_submit.  Thank you in advance to anyone that can help with this problem.

Comment: 1). Don't use `os.system`. Use `subprocess`. 2). It is `__init__` (two underscores), not `_init_`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, no wonder i could not retrieve the class variables, it was because I wasn't using __init__ with two underscores, that's why my class was so messed up.  Changed my code a bit and it worked great, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but I can make it do the right thing by getting rid of the class.  Here is what I have:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()

def buttonPressed():
    # this is the problem in the program.
    # it keeps returning [''] in the print statement and doesn't quit
    # any applications
    listOfApps = form.get().split(',')
    # the print is just so i can see the output
    print(listOfApps)
    # goes through each item in list and kills them(yes i know there are much easier
    # ways to do this, i'm just trying to learn a bit about GUI and the os module
    for i in listOfApps:
        try:
            os.system("killall " + i)
        except:
            pass
def buttonPressed2():
    filesToOpen = form2.get().split(', ')
    for i in filesToOpen:
        try:
            os.system("open " + i)
        except:
            pass

container = Frame(root)
form = Entry(container)
button = Button(container)
root['background'] = 'red'
container['background'] = 'red'
button['text'] = 'kill matching processes'
button['command'] = buttonPressed
form['background'] = 'red'
form['border'] = '5'
form['highlightthickness'] = '0'


container2 = Frame(root)
form2 = Entry(container2)
button2 = Button(container2)
root['background'] = 'blue'
container2['background'] = 'blue'
button2['text'] = 'Open desired files'
button2['command'] = buttonPressed2
form2['background'] = 'blue'
form2['border'] = '5'
form2['highlightthickness'] = '0'

container.pack()
form.pack()
button.pack()

container2.pack()
form2.pack()
button2.pack()

#starts up window
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the reason I was using classes was so that I could learn the syntax of it, I realize it could be done much easier without classes but this was just a practice program to help myself learn.